# Fullcalendar timeGridWeek - How to set row height to auto

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I am rendering a custom html for my calendar entries and they also look fine in the weekGridView. However, when I switch to timeGridView I have the issues that the row height stays fixed and does stretch to the height of the child elements.

[image]

What I would like to achieve is that the row expands and the entry with will be mounted with the top at 7 Uhr (7 AM).

All settings that I tried did not change this behaviour....

Comment: `the row height stays fixed`...it's meant to be a grid with fixed intervals between the times, so that it shows a coherent view of the day and you can visually see the length of events relative to each other. If you start stretching some slots bigger than others then it distorts that view and makes it look like some slots cover a larger time period than others, which is misleading.

Comment: I'm not sure how you ended up with this event element a full 2 hours away from its intended start time...you'd better show the code you're using to customise the event's appearance, and we can see if there's a better way to do it perhaps.

Comment: Thank you  @ADyson for the insight about the row height. Would have been nice to have a different options available. P.S. the issue about the different times is related to the timezone that is being into consideration while rendering the 7:00 but it is not important regarding the issue about the row height. Thanks :)